# Using Thread.Start() on a method that takes parameters and returns values

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I call a particular function on multiple threads as follows:

```
int q = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)
        {
            int copy = q;
            int copy1 = j;
            if (!display_status[copy1].Equals("NO") && (selection == "ALL" || (selection == "ALL-LAE" && license[copy1] != "") || (selection == "ALL-NON LAE" && license[copy1] == "") || (selection == "AVIONICS -ALL" && trade[copy1] == "Avionics") || (selection == "AVIONICS-NON LAE" && trade[copy1] == "Avionics" && license[copy1] == "") || (selection == "AVIONICS-LAE" && trade[copy1] == "Avionics" && license[copy1] != "") || (selection == "AIRFRAME-ALL" && trade[copy1] == "Airframes") || (selection == "AIRFRAME-NON LAE" && trade[j] == "Airframes" && license[j] == "") || (selection == "AIRFRAME-LAE" && trade[j] == "Airframes" && license[j] != "")))
            {
                int numberofprojects = numberc;
                string[] nameofproj = listc[0].ToArray();                    
                string[] name = list[0].ToArray();//list of manpower names
                string man_name = name[copy1];//Name of manpower
                List<string>[] lista = new List<string>[5];
                string[] status = listc[13].ToArray();
                thread[copy] = new Thread(() => {new_value[copy]=graph1threader(man_name,numberofprojects, nameofproj, status);});
                thread[copy].Start();
                q++;

            }
        }
```

graphthreader1() does not seem to be returning any value, as all elements of new_value hold the value 0 even after the function is called. What may be the reason? Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: None of those threads have finished.

Comment: How do I wait for them to finish, then?

Comment: Get rid of all of your code and use `Parallel.For`.

Comment: @SLaks He/she might be able to use the stuff in `graph1threader` :D

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve there (since I've never dealt with a thread returning anything), but the first thing I'd try, is moving your variables into a more global scope, and add a watch to these vars. Make sure your thread is running as you expect it to and that it's setting what needs to be set. If it's a value/reference problem then you'll know about it once you've figured out where the problem *isn't*. Isolate your problems.

Comment: I dont want to discuss your code in general, but can you call `Join` method for all of your spawned threads?

Comment: If .net 4 then why not using Task<ReturnValue> ? Task can return value, threads were not designed to. When using tasks, you can put them inside a collection and do Task.WaitAll(Collection of tasks)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that `graph1threader` has not finished yet, one way you can workaround this is by calling `thread[copy].Join()` but most likely this will defeat the purpose of using threads at all, another way will be by joining the first thread only at the end of the loop, but it depends on what you want to achieve with your code.